# Spotify: Adding a track to a playlist in iOS using Web API calls

Tags: ios, api, spotify

I'm trying to use some of the features of the Spotify web API along with the SDK (specifically to see if I can get more flexible track searching). I've achieved searching without a problem as it doesn't use authentication. However, trying to add a track to a playlist fails. I'm using the auth token that the SDK gives me, and I have privileges to read/write my playlists. I'm constructing the command as follows:

`requestFields = [requestFields stringByAppendingFormat:@"https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/my_name/playlists/0VpD39qOaV3AgYhaJsZCsm/tracks?uris=spotify:track:4iV5W9uYEdYUVa79Axb7Rh,spotify:track:1301WleyT98MSxVHPZCA6M -H ""Authorization: Bearer %@", auth.session.accessToken];`

which results in this:

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/my_name/playlists/0VpD39qOaV3AgYhaJsZCsm/tracks?uris=spotify:track:4iV5W9uYEdYUVa79Axb7Rh,spotify:track:1301WleyT98MSxVHPZCA6M%20-H%20Authorization:%20Bearer%20BQChUSzhHcb1qOwLYDr9jtYm3XU33VMi822Or8k4FgjDZ8L-qXWDQZB4o2sW9hEaSentuyTfT-cNR3oCLAV6rQqPuwP_SNCd9wy08tw9oTN7LisVTJ04VzJuxsaQWNl-uY23HTigbp9FS2fp6s2SRZy_sZRbCqS2vx7P_Uy6aqXOcxkkhPEoMk8XLeQWaY1cXuqp9VmGcLziAY6DImr5mp7jEvM8M7FWUiw0zMinGRcD7ExPLwe_zVMfM7pD
```

but it doesn't work and when I try the URL in a browser I get the following:

`{
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "This request requires authentication."
  }
}`

am I forming the URL incorrectly?

Comment: Are you sure you're sending the Authorization header correctly? It looks like you're making the `-H Authorization` part of the query parameters instead of actually sending a header. The response from the Web API is the same as if you'd ignored sending an access token.

Answer (score 1):

I used AFNetworking 1.3.4 for this solution. I created an AFHTTPClient called spotifyHTTPClient, and set the following code:

```
[self.spotifyHttpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Authorization" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",[SPTAuth defaultInstance].session.accessToken]];
[self.spotifyHttpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
```

This should solve your issues with the headers. This link also helped:
http://samwize.com/2012/10/25/simple-get-post-afnetworking/

This won't work if you just run it in the browser because your browser isn't setting the headers, but it will work if you run a simple test from Xcode